# How to iframe a html page without downloading it

Tags: html, iframe

i'm making a website that iframes Minecraft ([eaglercraft](https://eaglercraft.ru/)) from https://cdn-148.anonfiles.com/D8e7xed2z9/d0d37c1d-1678518568/mc.html but when i try putting it inside an iframe, it starts downloading it, i don't know if it matters that i'm using ChromeOS, can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely due to the server hosting the file not supplying the proper headers indicating that it should be displayed within an iframe.
can you send your code !

Comment: i don't have a code jet, because i really don't know how to to it...